# Getting error Object Required: when indexing an array

Tags: vbscript, scope

Here's the code:

```
Set page = Sys.Browser("iexplore").Page...

Set files_table = page.FindChildByXPath("//div[@class='dojoxGridContent']//div[@role='presentation']", True)

Set files_table_rows = files_table.children

row_index = 0

While Not file_found 
   lnk_Refresh.Click
   aqUtils.Delay(6000)
   Set cell = files_table_rows(row_index) //error thrown on this line
```

During debugging I can see both objects `files_table` and `files_table_rows` and they're both correct and have the correct data. When we try to get the first element in `files_table_rows`, we get an error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error.
>   Object required:'files_table_rows(...)'

If I place this line of code:

```
Set cell = files_table_rows(row_index)
```

right before the `While` loop, cell gets set correctly. The issue is happening inside the `While` loop, and I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: `lnk_Refresh.Click` probably invalidates the page, so `files_table_rows` no longer points to an existing object

Comment: That was exactly the issue @oraclecertifiedprofessional, I had to move those lines of code into the While loop.